# jQuery get all plugins executed against selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there a way to figure out all jQuery plugins executed against a jQuery selector?

Best regards.

Comment: use your console(profiling) , I am not sure about the plugin

Comment: I mean plug-ins that is executed against particular dom element.

Comment: you can check the `__proto__` of the selected element. It shows all supported method.

Comment: @Mohit Pandey __proto__ property displays all supported method including available plugins into $.fn namespace but I want to have a list with executed plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that it is impossible. No built-in API for this in JQuery.